# Setting an array variable that is passed by reference

Tags: powershell

I have an array object variable as `[ref] $InsertColHeadName = @()` in a function and then call another function with `param ([ref] $InsertColHeadName)`.  In the called function I then tried refering to my parameter set in param `([ref] $InsertColHeadName) += expression`. The expression returns a string. I placed a breakpoint in the line and tried forcing a string with single quotes eg.: `([ref] $InsertColHeadName) += 'xyz';`.

I tried googling around but can't seem to find a suitable solution.

I am getting the following error:

```
Method invocation failed because [System.Management.Automation.PSReference`1
[[System.Management.Automation.PSReference`1
[[System.Management.Automation.PSReference`1
[[System.Object[], mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]], System.Management.Automation, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35]], System.Management.Automation, 
Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35]]] does not
contain a method named 'op_Addition'.
At line:1 char:1
+ ([ref] $InsertColHeadName) += 'DepartmentNo';
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (op_Addition:String) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MethodNotFound
```

Comment: Why are you using `[ref]$arr = @()` instead of `$arr = @()` in the first place?

Comment: Before I was using it inside the main function and it did not need the reference. As the main function uses a particular logic a couple of times that is the same that has some validation logic I thought it would be better to push it to a function and call the function. The variable I am trying to reference is used in another function call that may need the variable to be available.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Still confused on how to do it with the array set as `$InsertColHeadName = @()` but went around it the following way.

In the main function I created the array as `Array = New-Object System.Collections.Generic.List[System.Object]`. When calling the function I passed the parameter as `([ref] $InsertColHeadName)`.

Inside the calling function in param I set up the parameter as `[ref] $InsColHeadName` as a new name as to not mix it up with the main function to make maintenence a little easier and then added the value to the array by doing `($InsColHeadName.Value).Add(...);`.

The above made the passing by reference to work when it returned back to the main function.

Answer (score 3):

Inside the function the InsertColHeadName is already a reference. Adding [ref] to it creates a reference of the reference.

instead try :

```
$InsertColHeadName.Value += expression
```

Here is an example:

```
function AddMe([ref]$array)
{
    $array.value += 40
}

$x = @(1..10)

Write-Host Before Calling AddMe $x
AddMe ([ref]$x)
Write-Host After Calling AddMe $x
```

The output:

```
Before Calling AddMe 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
After Calling AddMe 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 40
```

Answer (score 1):

Had this same issue.  Just have to make sure you do not cast the object to [ref] multiple times.  It's like casting [ref][ref][ref]$YourObject.

Answer (score 0):

When using [ref] with params, we have to refer to the passed parameter via `$parameter.Value` instead of just `$parameter`:

```
function Foo-Bar {
    param (
        [ref]$array
    )
    Write-Host $array

    $array.Value += { Title="a" }
    
}

$externalArray = New-Object System.Collections.Generic.List[System.Object]
$externalArray += { Title="initial" }

Foo-Bar -a ([ref]$externalArray)
```

- Works `$array.Value += { Title="a" }`
- Does not work: $array+= { Title="a" }